# Virtualbox: Windows XP guest on Linux host does not resize when window resizes

Tags: virtualbox

I have for years been using VirtualBox under Linux (currently Ubuntu 9.10) to run Windows XP Pro as a guest OS.  It worked fine until today, for some reason, the Windows guest stopped resizing to match the size of the VB window.  Also, the maximum resolution permitted by Windows is now 800x600.  I have upgraded to the latest stable VirtualBox and reinstalled the Guest Additions without changing anything.  Any suggestions?  I'd rather not revert to the last snapshot if possible because I've installed lots of software since, e.g. Adobe Flex Builder.

EDIT:  I tried starting a CentOS virtual machine and while it works fine in text mode, it cannot display in X (black window), indicating that the problem is either in VirtualBox itself or in Xorg.  Ubuntu did update Xorg recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to waste Molly's time.  Purging and reinstalling VirtualBox seems to have fixed it. I imagine some setting was wrong, but since I use this VM for work I couldn't leave it unfixed long enough to debug.

Comment: not to worry. you got it fixed, that's what matters :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the key combination HOST + G to toggle automatic resizing.  This is also available through the menu Machine -> Autoresize guest display.